# Updating downloading progress using withContext(Dispatchers.Main) slows down downloading process in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've run into a weird situation where updating the progress of download process slows down the overall download speed. If I don't show download progress, the download is completed in 2 minutes. Whereas, if I do show download progress, downloading takes 20 to 30 minutes.

As far as I understand, it has something to do with my lack of understanding of coroutines and switching dispatchers. But maybe that's not the case.

Here is the complete code:

```
private fun setDownloadClickListener() {
    binding.downloadIcon.setOnClickListener {

        binding.downloadIcon.gone()
        binding.downloadProgressTextView.visible()
        binding.downloadProgressTextView.text = "0.00"
        binding.downloadProgressBar.visible()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            
            try {
                downloadFile { progress ->
                    println("Download Progress: $progress")
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        binding.downloadProgressTextView.text = progress.toDecimalPoints(2)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                binding.downloadIcon.visible()
            }
            
            binding.downloadProgressTextView.text = ""
            binding.downloadProgressTextView.gone()
            binding.downloadProgressBar.gone()
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that downloadFile function internally switches dispatcher using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

```
suspend fun downloadFile(
    progressListener: (suspend (Float) -> Unit)? = null
) {

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        var linkFileSize: Int

        if (downloadFile.exists().not()) {
            downloadFile.parentFile?.mkdirs()
            downloadFile.createNewFile()
        }

        URL(fileLink)
            .also { linkFileSize = it.openConnection().contentLength }
            .openStream().use { downloadStream ->
                FileOutputStream(downloadFile).use { fos ->
                    val data = ByteArray(CHUNK_SIZE)
                    var count: Int
                    var bytesDownloaded = 0
                    while (
                        downloadStream.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)
                            .also {
                                count = it
                                bytesDownloaded += count
                            } != -1
                    ) {
                        fos.write(data, 0, count)
                        progressListener?.invoke(bytesDownloaded.toFloat() / linkFileSize.toFloat())
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show downloadFile function also

Comment: Yes, cannot tell what’s going on without seeing that code. But you shouldn’t use a UI coroutine to download a big file anyway. Users are not going to expect their download to get cancelled if they don’t stay on your screen for two continuous minutes.

Comment: Of course I'm not downloading it on UI coroutine. It's being done on IO coroutine, as mentioned above.

Comment: Please check my question with updated code now, thank you.